# Class path resource for JLabel ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, embedded-resource

I want to add a image in `JLabel` that can display after building the project too in eclipse.

I have this code..

```
 jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/student/information/system/images/bk4.jpg")));
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: After building the file the image is not visible. ma'am

Comment: Make sure your image is inside that package. If it is then try this `./student/information/system/images/bk4.jpg` `.` before `/`

Comment: *"image is not visible"* Show the project structure (the packages leading to that image). Note that `getResource` is case sensitive.

Comment: Did you read the _javadoc_ for method [`getResource()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) ? If you did, was there something you did not understand?

Answer (score 1):

Goodness, why are you trying to read an image file in one line?

First, make sure that your resources folder is defined for your project and is on the build path.

Here's an example from one of my Java projects.

[image: Build Path]

Next, code a method to read image files from the resources folder.

```
private Image getImage(String filename) {
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "/" + filename));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Read the image file once, saving the result in a class variable  `ImageIcon`.

```
imageIcon = new ImageIcon(getImage("image.png"));
```

Finally, reference the ImageIcon in your Swing code.

```
jLabel1.setIcon(imageIcon);
```