# Images in Java coming up NPE

Tags: java, image, swing, nullpointerexception, embedded-resource

I was trying out putting images in java. My end goal is to make a image I can control with arrow keys, but I can't seem to put an image in. I imported the image, and I have the name correct. I keep getting a null pointer exception.

code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JPanel {
public static ImageIcon image;


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("rocketJava.jpg"));
        image.paintIcon(this,g, 20, 20);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f= new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Test s = new Test();
        f.add(s);

        f.setSize(600,600);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try giving the name along with the path or store the image in the src/main/resource folder.

Comment: please post the error stack trace and point out the line in the code which throws the exception

Comment: Maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55450014/class-path-resource-for-jlabel-imageicon/61851663#61851663

Comment: The error is the line where I set image = to the image icon

Comment: Gilbert I tried that but it did not work. I am thinking maybe I should try adding it to a JLabel instead.

Comment: 1) Do not attempt to load an image in any paint method. Instead load it once in a constructor or initialization method. 2) When loading, use `ImageIO` to load the image itself. 3) Ensure the case of the letters are correct. 4) Don't store the image in the root of a project. It will typically not be included in the Jar, and will therefore be unavailable to load. 5) Prefix the image path with `/`. 6) *"I should try adding it to a JLabel instead"* No, you shouldn't. That won't solve the NPE.

Comment: Andrew I figured it out. I needed to put the things in the bin folder. Thanks though. I am still using JLabel to do it.

Comment: *"I figured it out."* Congrats! Now you might write an answer below, or simply delete the question using the link below it. BTW Tip: Add @GilbertLeBlanc (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was just that I needed to move the picture file to the bin folder.